# Laravel - CKEditor toolbar not loaded if using mysite.dev:8080

Tags: laravel-4, ckeditor

CKEditor toolbar not loaded if I use *mysite.dev:8080* . But its loaded in *localhost/mysite/public*

I put CKEditor in *mysite/vendor/ckeditor*

In layout.blade.php I put CKEditor javascript and CKEditor textarea as below:

> {{ Form::textarea('content',null,['class' => 'ckeditor']) }} 
>  {{
>   HTML::script('../vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'); }}

--version used--

```
Laravel 4.2
CKEditor 3.6
Apache 2.4.6
```

--apache httpd.conf virtual host setting--

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost mysite.dev:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public
ServerName mysite.dev
# Other Apache config directives, logs etc.
</VirtualHost>
```

--etc/hosts--

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mysite.dev
```

Comment: Try clearing server cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, find workaround by my self in two different ways:

1. Its turn Ok if I put full path of ckeditor.js as below

   {{ HTML::script('//localhost/mysite/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'); }}
2. Put ckeditor folder in public, and not in vendor as before (is there any security issue if I do this ?).

Still hope someone explain why laravel cant point relative path of ckeditor.js

And its not server cache, Apul Gupta.